# Are AWS ElastiCache Reserved instances size-flexible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache, aws-reserved-instances

I am currently looking into purchasing a bunch of ElasiCache reserved instances.

I know from EC2 and RDS, that it does not matter if you purchase e.g. a `t3.medium` or 2 `t3.small` instances, because the reserved instances are [size-flexible](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ri-size-flexibility/)

Is this also the case for reserved ElasiCache instances?

I can not find any hint about it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/reserved-cache-nodes/) or [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheNodes.Reserved.html)...

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question, the answer is **no**.

I found this in the Recomendation page:

[image]